# Edit Bootstrap style profile cards

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Seen code for various styles of profile cards but not on how to edit them. I wanted to see how to edit a profile card to add onto my website?

Comment: Add some code or links to what you have and what you want

Comment: Sorry about that! Here is what I would like to use:  https://www.webnots.com/bootstrap-4-user-profile-card-widget/ I want to use this profile style card. How do I edit this?